# How to pass a parameter to a function of an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, object, parameter-passing

I apologize, if this is a dublicate, but I can't find the answer I am looking for, although my problem seems to be easy.

This is what I have:

```
function myMain (myParam) {

    var myObj = {

        myVal1 : 'demo',
        myFunc : function (myParam) {
            console.log (myParam);
        }
    };

    runDemo(myObj);

}
```

My problem is that I want the `console.log` to write `myParam` of `myMain`, but it is `undefined` - why?

How can I call `myMain('works')` so that console writes `works`?

FYI: `runDemo` has too be called with this single Object and with myFunc as one of the objects values - no way around that. I am grateful for any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make myFunc not take a parameter like so:

```
function myMain (myParam) {

    var myObj = {

        myVal1 : 'demo',
        myFunc : function () {
            console.log (myParam);
        }
    };

    runDemo(myObj);

}
```

In this case `myFunc` retains the value of the variable `myParam`. This is called a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: nice, this works - I still do not quite get why, but it does ... thanks for the super fast answer! I will look up 'closure', but feel free to explain further ;)

Comment: It is similar to this: `var a = 'foo'; function bar(){alert(a);}`